# Inserting EventData to SQL table using where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple logging script that populates a change log table from a trigger, I am trying to limit the rows inserted by excluding inserts for a certain schema (chi)

Trigger:

```
 DECLARE @data XML
 SET @data = EVENTDATA()

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Object_ChangeLog](databasename, eventtype, objectname, objecttype, sqlcommand, loginname)
 VALUES (@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
         @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), 
         @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'), 
         @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 
         @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
         @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'))
```

And I need to use a where clause to filter out object changes under schema name (chi) - so far I have tried:

```
WHERE 
    @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)') NOT LIKE 'chi%'
```

Unfortunately this generates a syntax error, there are 2 issues, firstly is there a separate column I need to bring through from the event data to identify the schema? and secondly how can I utilize the where clause to remove these from the inserts within the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seems to be procedural code, you may simply use `IF`.

```
...
IF @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)') NOT LIKE 'chi%'
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Object_ChangeLog](databasename, eventtype, 
  objectname, objecttype, sqlcommand, loginname)
  VALUES(
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), 
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'), 
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
  );
END;
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much - is there another column I can bring through form the event data to identify the schema?

Comment: @jimmy8ball: You can try if `SchemaName`  is available for your event(s).